# Applying a bank of image filters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, vectorization, convolution

I need to filter an image using a bank of filters in Matlab.  My first attempt was to use a simple for loop to repeatedly call the "imfilter" function for each filter in the bank.

I will need to repeat this process many times for my application, so I need to this step to be as efficient as possible.  Therefore, I was wondering if there was any way this operation could be vectorized to speed up the process.  In an effort to simplify things, all of my filter kernels are the same size (9x9).

As an example of what I am going for, my filters are set up in a 9x9x32 element block, which needs to be applied to my image.  I thought about replicating the image into a block (e.g. 100x100x32), but I'm not sure if there's a way to apply an operation like convolution without resorting to loops.  Does anyone have suggestions for a good way of tackling this problem?

Comment: Just as an addendum to this question: I realized that I might be better served by filtering in the frequency domain rather than using convolution in the spatial domain. I haven't actually put this to the test yet, but I think I should be able to take the FFT of the image, tile the result, and then do a vectorized multiplication to apply the bank of filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Answer: Use colfilt() or block filtering style. Matlab can transform your image into large matrix where each distinct 9x9 pixel area is a single column (81 elements). Make it using im2col() method. If your image is N by M the result matrix would be 81 X (N-8)*(M-8).

Then you can concatenate all your filters to single matrix (each filter is a row) and multiply those huge matrices. This will give you the result of all filters. Now you have to reconstruct back 32 result images from the result matrix. use col2im() method.
For more information type 'doc colfilt'

This method works almost as fast as mex file and doesnt require any 'for' loop

Old answer:

Do you want to get different 32 results or single result for combination of filters?
If it is a sungle result than there is an easy way.
If you use linear filters (like convolutions) then apply filters one on another. Finally apply the resulting filter on the image. Thus image will be convolved only once.
If you filters are symmetric (x and y direction) then instead of applying the 9x9 filter apply 9x1 on y direction and 1x9 on x direction. Works a bit faster.
Finally, you can try using Mex file

Comment: I should clarify: I need separate output images for each filter rather than simply applying all of the filters to the image sequentially.

Comment: Thanks! That's just the sort of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Other than pre allocating the space, there is not a faster way to arrive at an exact solution.  If approximations are ok, then you might be able to decompose the 32 filters into a set of linear combinations of a smaller number of filters, say eight.   See for instance Steerable filters.

http://people.csail.mit.edu/billf/papers/steerpaper91FreemanAdelson.pdf

edit: here is a tool to help apply filters to images.

```
function FiltIm = ApplyFilterBank(im,filters)
%#function FiltIm = ApplyFilterBank(im,filters)
%#
%#assume im is a single layer image, and filters is a cell array

nFilt = length(filters);
maxsz = 0;
for i = 1:nFilt
  maxsz = max(maxsz,max(size(filters{i})));
end
FiltIm = zeros(size(im,1), size(im,2), nFilt);
im = padimage(im,maxsz,'symmetric');
for i = 1:nFilt
  FiltIm(:,:,i) = unpadimage(imfilter(im,filters{i}),maxsz);
end

function o = padimage(i,amnt,method)
%#function o = padimage(i,amnt,method)
%#
%#padarray which operates on only the first 2 dimensions of a 3 dimensional
%#image. (of arbitrary number of layers);
%#
%#String values for METHOD
%#        'circular'    Pads with circular repetion of elements.
%#        'replicate'   Repeats border elements of A.
%#        'symmetric'   Pads array with mirror reflections of itself. 
%#
%#if(amnt) is length 1, then pad all sides same amount
%#
%#if(amnt) is length 2, then pad y direction amnt(1), and x direction amnt(2)
%#
%#if(amnt) is length 4, then pad sides unequally with order LTRB, left top right bottom
if(nargin < 3)
   method = 'replicate';
end
if(length(amnt) == 1)
  o = zeros(size(i,1) + 2 * amnt, size(i,2) + 2* amnt, size(i,3));
  for n = 1:size(i,3)
    o(:,:,n) = padarray(i(:,:,n),[amnt,amnt],method,'both');
  end
end
if(length(amnt) == 2)
  o = zeros(size(i,1) + 2 * amnt(1), size(i,2) + 2* amnt(2), size(i,3));
  for n = 1:size(i,3)
    o(:,:,n) = padarray(i(:,:,n),amnt,method,'both');
  end
end
if(length(amnt) == 4)
  o = zeros(size(i,1) + amnt(2) + amnt(4), size(i,2) + amnt(1) + amnt(3), size(i,3));
  for n = 1:size(i,3)
    o(:,:,n) = padarray(padarray(i(:,:,n),[amnt(2), amnt(1)],method,'pre'),[amnt(4),     amnt(3)],method,'post');
  end
end

function o = unpadimage(i,amnt)
%#un does padimage
%#if length(amnt == 1), unpad equal on each side
%#if length(amnt == 2), first amnt is left right, second up down
%#if length(amnt == 4), then [left top right bottom];

switch(length(amnt))
case 1
  sx = size(i,2) - 2 * amnt;
  sy = size(i,1) - 2 * amnt;
  l = amnt + 1;
  r = size(i,2) - amnt;
  t = amnt + 1;
  b = size(i,1) - amnt;
case 2
  sx = size(i,2) - 2 * amnt(1);
  sy = size(i,1) - 2 * amnt(2);
  l = amnt(1) + 1;
  r = size(i,2) - amnt(1);
  t = amnt(2) + 1;
  b = size(i,1) - amnt(2);
case 4
  sx = size(i,2) - (amnt(1) + amnt(3));
  sy = size(i,1) - (amnt(2) + amnt(4));
  l = amnt(1) + 1;
  r = size(i,2) - amnt(3);
  t = amnt(2) + 1;
  b = size(i,1) - amnt(4);
otherwise
  error('illegal unpad amount\n');
end
if(any([sx,sy] < 1))
    fprintf('unpadimage newsize < 0, returning []\n');
    o = [];
    return;
end

o = zeros(sy, sx, size(i,3));
for n = 1:size(i,3)
  o(:,:,n) = i(t:b,l:r,n);
end
```

Comment: It looks like the code you provided does basically the same thing I'm already doing, but with the filters stored as a cell array rather than a 3D block.

I guess I'm not shocked that there is no faster way of doing this operation, but I was hoping I might be missing something. As it stands, this operation takes like 80% of the processing time in my program.